# Crossing Canadian to USA border with dried food

Tags: usa, food-and-drink, driving

I have made all my own dried food ie. soups, chilli, tofu jerky. We were supposed to go to Jasper for a 7 day hiking trip but due to fires we are now going to Yellowstone.

Can I bring my dried foods?

Comment: From where to where? Which border?

Comment: Presumably from Canada to the USA.

Answer (score 3):

From context, I assume you mean Canada to USA.  If this is correct, the answer is **yes, you can**, at least if you're crossing overland.

I have gone hiking in the USA before, while living in Canada.  I drove a car over the border between Ontario and New York (state).  Due to my Dutch passport I had to enter the tiny border crossing office and I was interrogated by the border officer.  Among other things, he asked what I was bringing, and I made a detailed description; it included dried food.  This was no problem at all.

It may be different if you fly.

Full details are available at CBPs page on [bringing food into the U.S. for personal use](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/82/~/travelers-bringing-food-into-the-u.s.-for-personal-use).

Comment: A Canadian or US citizen making this crossing would not usually need to go into the office, but [this page](http://www.cbp.gov/travel/clearing-cbp/bringing-agricultural-products-united-states) from US customs says that they should declare the "agricultural products."  In all likelihood they will have a similar experience to yours, but it may be better to be safe than sorry. ...

Comment: ... I have declared foods in the past (at airports, arriving from Western Europe) and also that I had been in close proximity to livestock (during a bike tour in the province of North Holland) and in all cases have been admitted without any further inspection.